# why jquery click event fires twice

Tags: jquery

This is my `html`:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-links proceed button-success">
    <span class="menue-title" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 3px;">Proceed</span>
    <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
</a>
```

This is the `jquery`

```
$('.proceed').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
});
```

And this is what is causing my problem

```
$('.proceed').trigger('click');
```

When i manually click on that button the event fires once. But when i call the `trigger('click')` function that click event fires twice.

A more detailed diagnosis:

When i click the button manually, `console.log` shows either `A` or `SPAN` or `I` only once (depending on which part of the button i'm clicking). But when i call the `trigger` function, `console.log` shows `A` twice.

I have tried these:

`$('.proceed').off().on('click', function (e) {});`
`e.preventDefault();`
`e.stopPropagation();`
`e.stopImmediatePropagation();`
`return false;`

But nothing solved the problem. What is actually causing the problem and how do i solve it? How do i make the `trigger` function fire the `click` event only once?

Comment: I think somehow, you would be attaching "click" event to the control more than once. Try removing "click" event handler before attaching the "click" event handler. That is, use "off() method of jQuery"

Comment: adding `off()` not working

Comment: i cannot replicate your problem. Can you make a snippet that replicates it ? https://jsfiddle.net/qwu6r3n0/ . Where/When is the trigger method called?

Comment: generally it should not happen.. can you please share the code so that we can have a look where you are making mistake.  Generally it will log `element` only once. Check fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/34pnu5kw/

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem in a clean project/solution/file/snippet/jsfiddle?  You'll find that it works as expected (as shown above with two example jsfiddles).  So whatever is causing the problem is something *outside* what you've described here.  You may have a 2nd click event handler setup or (most likely) called the `.on("click")` twice (though `.off()` should have fixed that).  Any solution provided here would be based on other people's experience rather than what your problem is so will be essentially guesswork.   Try to creating an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to put breakpoint on `console.log` trigger input using js and debug stacktrace?

Comment: i was trying to replicate that problem in jsfiddle but i figured that it works as expected on jsfiddle. anyways i'm sharing my full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `.proceed` class twice in your html.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake. Ok I had a hidden button element with the same class. Thanks. BTW I cant show all the codes. Both the HTML and the JS files are huge, that's why it missed my eye I guess.

Comment: glad to help, everyone makes mistakes:)